# Asp.NET return empy List<Object> C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, null, return

In my ASP.NET classic WebForms application, I have a class that returns a list of `Role` objects that I use for mapping the roles of the users in my database.

I wrote this static class:

```
public static class RoleHelper
{
    public static List<RoleValue> getRoles()
    {
        List<RoleValue> myroles = null;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                dbconn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT groupID,Name FROM Gruppi", dbconn);
                cmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                cmd.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    myroles = new List<RoleValue>();

                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        RoleValue myrole = new RoleValue();
                        myrole.roleID = (int)row["groupID"]; ;
                        myrole.roleName = (string)row["Name"]; ;
                        myroles.Add(myrole);
                    }
                }
                dbconn.Close();
            }
        }
        return myroles;
    }
}
```

At first I wrote:

```
List(RoleValue) myroles = null;
```

Is this wrong?

In the calling function, I check  `if (rolesList.Count > 0)` but I should check `if(!rolesList is null)` but null isn't allowed for lists?

Comment: I have no problem. I had only the doubt about the right approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not wrong to initialize a list to `null`, but it is more widely used this way:

```
List<RoleValue> myroles = new List<RoleValue>();
```

Then you would return the list and the caller would check the length of the list to see if is empty, like this:

```
List<RoleValue> listOfRoles = getRoles();

if(listOfRoles.Count == 0)
{
    // Report message to user if having no roles is worthy of a notification
}
```

The advantage to returning an instance of a list versus `null` is that most operations a user will do will work without checking for `null`, such as databinding and iterating over the list.

Comment: returning `null` is often used to indicate an error. But this should of course be indicated by throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in the normal case db access works, so you will reach

```
myroles = new  List<RoleValue>();
```

Therefore you might create this instance already on top, instead of

```
List<RoleValue> myroles = null;
```

Advantage: the caller can iterate over all roles, if the collection is empty, simply no output will be created.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, you should instead initialize it to an empty list, rather than `null`, and check to see if it has any items rather than seeing if it's `null` elsewhere.  This prevents the need to riddle all code using the type to check for null, most operations *should* work properly (i.e. do nothing) if there are no items, such as `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a list with 0 objects and returning null are both perfectly valid. What you need to focus on is what the caller should expect from the method. Should they receive an empty list? This would let them avoid having to do a null check first.

Answer (score 0):

In general it could be null. But i think your if-clause is always true or sth. so that this line will be done myroles = new  List(); Then it isnt null. Better ask for .Count Property